# [NSPlaceholderMutableString initWithString:]: nil argument exception coming after casting the UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I have a code like this.

```
else if ([controlIn isKindOfClass:UITextField.class]) {
    UITextField *cast = (UITextField *)controlIn;
    if (cast.inputView != NULL) {
        cast.text = [self setResolvedValue:cast metrixUIViewControllerIn:metrixUIViewControllerIn valueIn:valueIn];
    } else {
        cast.text = valueIn;
    }
```

But in this `if (cast.inputView != NULL)` line I am getting an exception

> "[NSPlaceholderMutableString initWithString:]: nil argument"

My `cast` is not nil. But whats the reason to get this error. Please help me.
Thanks

**UPDATE**

```
+ (NSString*) setResolvedValue:(UIView *)viewIn metrixUIViewControllerIn:(MetrixUIViewController *)metrixUIViewControllerIn valueIn:(NSString *)valueIn {
NSMutableString *resolvedValue = [NSMutableString stringWithString:valueIn];
if (![MetrixStringHelper isNullOrEmpty:valueIn] && [viewIn.inputView isKindOfClass:[UIPickerView class]]) {
    MetrixColumnDef *columnDef = [MetrixControlAssistant getColumnDefAssociatedToPicker:metrixUIViewControllerIn picker:(UIPickerView *)viewIn.inputView];
    NSString *uniqueName = [MetrixControlAssistant getUniqueNameAssociatedToPicker:metrixUIViewControllerIn picker:(UIPickerView *)viewIn.inputView];
    NSMutableArray *dataSet = [metrixUIViewControllerIn.pickerData objectForKey:uniqueName];
    for (NSDictionary *dictionary in dataSet) {
        if ([MetrixStringHelper value:valueIn isEqualTo:[dictionary objectForKey:columnDef.lookupDef.valueColumn]]) {
            resolvedValue = [dictionary objectForKey:columnDef.lookupDef.displayColumn];
            break;
        }
    }
}
return resolvedValue;
```

}

Comment: Let try to check by `if (cast.inputView)` instead of `if (cast.inputView != NULL)`

Comment: @trungduc still same :(

Comment: Could you show the `setResolvedValue` method?

Comment: @trungduc I updated the question with that part. But this is even not going inside the if statement. It jumping to the exception on the condition line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because of `valueIn` is nil when you initialize `resolvedValue`. Check and make sure `valueIn` isn't nil before using it to initialize `resolvedValue`.

You should take a look at Apple document for [stringWithString:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1497372-stringwithstring) method.

> Raises an NSInvalidArgumentException if aString is nil.

Try to replace your method by the code below

```
+ (NSString*) setResolvedValue:(UIView *)viewIn metrixUIViewControllerIn:(MetrixUIViewController *)metrixUIViewControllerIn valueIn:(NSString *)valueIn {
  if ([MetrixStringHelper isNullOrEmpty:valueIn] || ![viewIn.inputView isKindOfClass:[UIPickerView class]]) {
    return @"";
  }

  NSMutableString *resolvedValue = [NSMutableString stringWithString:valueIn];
  MetrixColumnDef *columnDef = [MetrixControlAssistant getColumnDefAssociatedToPicker:metrixUIViewControllerIn picker:(UIPickerView *)viewIn.inputView];
  NSString *uniqueName = [MetrixControlAssistant getUniqueNameAssociatedToPicker:metrixUIViewControllerIn picker:(UIPickerView *)viewIn.inputView];
  NSMutableArray *dataSet = [metrixUIViewControllerIn.pickerData objectForKey:uniqueName];
  for (NSDictionary *dictionary in dataSet) {
    if ([MetrixStringHelper value:valueIn isEqualTo:[dictionary objectForKey:columnDef.lookupDef.valueColumn]]) {
      resolvedValue = [dictionary objectForKey:columnDef.lookupDef.displayColumn];
      break;
    }
  }
  return resolvedValue;
}
```

Comment: But why its crashing on the condition line. If the error is with this line it should atleast go to inside isnt it?

Comment: Actually, i don't know. But with the error log, the problem is when you initialize `resolveValue`.  Maybe Xcode isn't always right ;)

Comment: But still same :(

Comment: Sorry my bad, i have updated my answer. You can try it again.

Comment: Thanks! It worked. :) Still I cant imagine why it didnt give the crash on this line. Can you explain that exception little bit? [NSPlaceholderMutableString initWithString:]: nil argument